# Show pages and articles in category search result

Tags: categories, pages

I'm using "Map Categories to Pages" to add categories to pages.

When I call the link http://mypage.com/category/catA+catB I get all my articles, that are associated to the categories catA and catB. What I'm looking for is:

A) a way to do something similar with pages: call http://mypage.com/pages/catA+catB and get all pages that are associates to the categories catA and catB

-or-

B) a way to get first pages and then articles, on the category search result page, like:

- Some Page
- Another Page
- Some Article
- Another Article
- One more Article

Comment: why not use : http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_pages
and include exclude by getting id's of the pages by categories?

Comment: What is a "category search result" page? Category archive index pages and search results index pages are two entirely different things. To which one of the two are you referring?

Comment: @ChipBennett sorry, I meant the category archive, not the search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display pages in a category archive index:

1. Add category taxonomy to the `Page` post-type

   Static pages, by default, do not have any taxonomies associated with them, including the `category` taxonomy. So you need to register the `category` taxonomy for the `page` post type, using [**`register_taxonomy_for_object_type()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy_for_object_type):

   ```
   function wpse94150_register_category_taxonomy_for_page_post_type() {
       register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'page' );
   }
   add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpse94150_register_category_taxonomy_for_page_post_type' );
   ```
2. Create Pages with Categories

   Self-explanatory. For pages to appear in a category archive index, you'll need to have pages that have categories assigned.
3. Filter Query to include the page post-type for Category archive index pages

   Next, you need to tell WordPress to [include the `'page'` post-type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_Parameters) in the results for the category archive index query, by filtering the `$query` object via [**`pre_get_posts`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts):

   ```
   function wpse94150_filter_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
       // Only modify the main loop query
       // on category archive index pages
       if ( $query->is_main_query && $query->is_category() ) {
           // Return both posts and pages
           $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page' ) );
       }
   }
   add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse94150_filter_pre_get_posts' );
   ```
4. View category archive index pages, now with posts and pages

   Navigate to `example.com/category/cat-a`, and if you have Pages assigned to "Cat A", you will see them in the archive index.

### Edit

> 1. Where do I enter the code from step 3?

I would put the code from step 3 in the same place you put the code from step 1: ideally in a site functionality Plugin, or as a less-ideal backup, in the `functions.php` file of a Child Theme.

> And 2. Will this change be stable if I update WordPress or it's plugins?

Since these changes are not made directly to any core or Plugin file: yes, the changes are stable and future-proof. (Unless WordPress changes one of the underlying APIs or hooks, which is extremely doubtful.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I've got two questions: 1. Where do I enter the code from step 3? And 2. Will this change be stable if I update WordPress or it's plugins?

Comment: Please see updates to the answer, which address your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out, the "Map Categories to Pages" plugin has ist own Settings pages with an option "**Show the Pages on Category pages**", which does exactly what I want.

I marked Chip Bennett's answer anyway because it solves the problem without the plugin and it's very detailed. Thank's Chip.